# link button is not fireing but button is working

Tags: c#, ajax, linkbutton

I'm having two pages inbox.aspx and compose.aspx 
by ajax I'm loading the compose page inside a div in inbox page
so I'm facing a problem with form coz I'm using form in master page for inbox and in compose page
when I'm loading compose page i will have two nested form :(
i tried to omit it but the page won't load without it specially when i put asp control inside it 
till now every things worked without an error but in compose page i have link button when i click it I'm having an error 
(too much recursion,Empty string passed to getElementById())
and it is not firing , but asp:button tag is working  perfectly
here is the code

> inbox.aspx

```
<div class="row email">
                                <div id="list-toggle" class="col-md-2">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <li class="composeBtn">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Compose" class="btn Compose btn-danger">Compose
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="emailNav nav nav-pills nav-stacked margin-bottom-10">
                                        <li class="inbox active">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Inbox">
                                                <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-fw"></i>Inbox (2)
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="starred">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Starred">
                                                <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i>Starred
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="sent">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Sent">
                                                <i class="fa fa-mail-forward fa-fw"></i>Sent Items
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="draft">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Draft">
                                                <i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i>Drafts
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="spam">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Spam">
                                                <i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i>Spam
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="trash">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" data-title="Trash">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i>Trash
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="emailContent"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

> javascript
>   var Inbox = function () {

```
var main_content = $('.emailContent');
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show single email view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var showSingleEmail = function (el, name, resetMenu) {
    alert('');
    var url = 'inbox_email.html';
    main_content.html('');
    toggleButton(el);        
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(res) 
        {
            toggleButton(el);               
            main_content.html(res);                
            App.initUniform();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            toggleButton(el);
        },
        async: false
    });
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show WYSIWYG Editor
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var showWYSIWYG = function () {
    alert('');
    function initToolbarBootstrapBindings() {
      var fonts = ['Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier', 
            'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Tahoma', 'Times',
            'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'],
            fontTarget = $('[title=Font]').siblings('.dropdown-menu');
      $.each(fonts, function (idx, fontName) {
          fontTarget.append($('<li><a data-edit="fontName ' + fontName +'" style="font-family:\''+ fontName +'\'">'+fontName + '</a></li>'));
      });
      $('a[title]').tooltip({container:'body'});
        $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {return false;})
            .change(function () {$(this).parent('.dropdown-menu').siblings('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');})
        .keydown('esc', function () {this.value='';$(this).change();});

      $('[data-role=magic-overlay]').each(function () { 
        var overlay = $(this), target = $(overlay.data('target')); 
        overlay.css('opacity', 0).css('position', 'absolute').offset(target.offset()).width(target.outerWidth()).height(target.outerHeight());
      });
      if ("onwebkitspeechchange"  in document.createElement("input")) {
        var editorOffset = $('#editor').offset();
        $('#voiceBtn').css('position','absolute').offset({top: editorOffset.top, left: editorOffset.left+$('#editor').innerWidth()-35});
      } else {
        $('#voiceBtn').hide();
      }
    };
    function showErrorAlert (reason, detail) {
        var msg='';
        if (reason==='unsupported-file-type') { msg = "Unsupported format " +detail; }
        else {
            console.log("error uploading file", reason, detail);
        }
        $('<div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+ 
         '<strong>File upload error</strong> '+msg+' </div>').prependTo('#alerts');
    };
    initToolbarBootstrapBindings();  
    $('#editor').wysiwyg({ fileUploadError: showErrorAlert} );
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show Inbox view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var showInbox = function (el, name) {
    alert('');
    var url = 'inbox_main.html';      
    main_content.html('');
    toggleButton(el);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(res) 
        {
            toggleButton(el);               
            main_content.html(res);
            App.initUniform();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            toggleButton(el);
        },
        async: false
    });
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show email reply view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var showEmailReply = function (el) {
    alert('');
    var url = 'inbox_email_reply.html'; 
    main_content.html('');
    toggleButton(el);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(res) 
        {
            toggleButton(el);               
            main_content.html(res);
            handleCCControl();
            handleCCBCC();
            showWYSIWYG();
            $('#editor').html($('#reply-content').html());
            $('#reply-content').hide();                
            App.initUniform();
            $('#editor').focus();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            toggleButton(el);
        },
        async: false
    });
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show Compose view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var showCompose = function (el) {
    alert('');
    var url = 'InboxCompose.aspx';
    main_content.html('');

   //toggleButton(el);
    //
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: url,

        //dataType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(res) 
        {
           // $(".emailContent").load("InboxCompose.aspx  #EmailComposeContent");

           // toggleButton(el);
            //$(".emailContent").load("InboxCompose.aspx");
            main_content.html(res);
          //  showWYSIWYG();
        //  handleCCBCC();
        //    $('#editor').focus();                
         //   App.initUniform();
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            toggleButton(el);
        },
        async: false
    });
   // App.setPage("Teacher");  //Set current page
  //  App.setAction("ComposeEmail");  //Set current page
  //  App.init(); //Initialise plugins and elements
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show Compose view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var handleCCBCC = function () {
    alert('');
    $('.emailCompose .address').on('click', '.emailCC', function () {
        handleCCControl();
    });
    $('.emailCompose .address').on('click', '.emailBCC', function () {
        handleBCCControl();
    });
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show Compose view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var handleCCControl = function () {
    alert('');
    var the = $('.emailCompose .address .emailCC');
    var input = $('.emailCompose .inputCC');
    the.hide();
    input.show();
    $('.close', input).click(function () {
        input.hide();
        the.show();
    });
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Show Compose view
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var handleBCCControl = function () {
    alert('');
    var the = $('.emailCompose .address .emailBCC');
    var input = $('.emailCompose .inputBCC');
    the.hide();
    input.show();
    $('.close', input).click(function () {
        input.hide();
        the.show();
    });
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Toggle button
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
var toggleButton = function (el) {
    alert('');
    if (typeof el == 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    if (el.attr("disabled")) {
        el.attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        el.attr("disabled", true);
    }
}

return {
    init: function () {
         alert('');
        ///* Show main inbox screen */
        //$('.emailNav > li.inbox > a').click(function () {
        //    showInbox($(this), 'inbox');
        //});

        /* Show compose screen */
        $('.email .composeBtn').on('click', 'a.Compose', function () {
            showCompose($(this));
        });

        ///* Show email reply screen */
        //$('.email').on('click', '.replyBtn', function () {
        //    showEmailReply($(this));
        //});

        ///* Show single email screen */
        //$('.emailContent').on('click', '.viewEmail', function () {
        //    showSingleEmail($(this));
        //});

        ///* Handle CC control links */
        //$('.emailCompose .address').on('click', '.emailCC', function () {
        //    handleCCControl();
        //});

        ///* Handle BCC control links */
        //$('.emailCompose .address').on('click', '.emailBCC', function () {
        //    handleBCCControl();
        //});

        ///* Show main inbox for the first load */
        //$('.emailNav > li.inbox > a').click();
    }
};
```

}();

> Compose.aspx

```
 <html>

   <body>
      <form id="form" runat="server"  method="get">
          <div id="EmailComposeContent" class="emailCompose form-horizontal">
          <div class="emailField" >
              <label class="control-label  pl-none">
                  <span>To:</span>
              </label>
              <div class="fields col-md-11">
                  <asp:TextBox type="hidden" class="bigdrop js-data-example-ajax col-md-9 selectDynamic noborder" runat="server"
                      data-groupname="ToGroup" data-groupcontrol="ToGroupList"
                      ID="TextBoxToIDs" data-url="InboxCompose.aspx/GetXMLData" value="16340"></asp:TextBox>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                      <ul id="ToGroupList" class="pagination  pagination-sm mb-none  mt-none">
                          <li id="ParentGroup" class="anchor Sections "
                              onclick="setSection(this);">
                              <span class='f-lightergray'><span data-original-title="Parent" data-title="P" class="text">P</span>
                                  <input id='RadioParentGroup' name="ToGroup" checked="checked" type="radio" value="3" style="display: none" /></span>
                          </li>
                          <li id="StudentGroup" class="anchor Sections "
                              onclick="setSection(this);">
                              <span class='f-lightergray'><span data-original-title="Student" data-title="S" class="text">S</span>
                                  <input id='RadioStudentGroup' name="ToGroup" type="radio" value="2" style="display: none" /></span>
                          </li>
                          <li id="AdviserGroup" class="anchor Sections "
                              onclick="setSection(this);">
                              <span class='f-lightergray'><span data-original-title="Adviser" data-title="A" class="text">A</span>
                                  <input id='RadioAdviserGroup' name="ToGroup" type="radio" value="5" style="display: none" /></span>
                          </li>

                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>



          </div>


         <div class="emailField">
            <label class="control-label  ">
                Title:</label>
            <div class="fields col-md-9">
               <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="TextBoxTitle" runat="server"   type="text" ></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
         </div>

          <div class="emailField">
            <label class="control-label ">
                Expiry Date:</label>
            <div class="fields col-md-4">
          <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control datepicker" ID="TextBoxExpiryDate" runat="server"   type="text" ></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
               <label class="control-label ">
                Publish Date:</label>
            <div class="fields col-md-4"> 
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control datepicker" ID="TextBoxPublishDate" runat="server"   type="text" ></asp:TextBox>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="emailField">
            <div class="divide-20"></div>
            <div id="alerts"></div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="fa fa-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li><a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a></li>
                     <li><a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a></li>
                     <li><a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="fa fa-strikethrough"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></a>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="fa fa-outdent"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i></a>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="fa fa-align-center"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="fa fa-align-right"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></a>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
                     <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
                     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add</button>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="unlink" title="Remove Hyperlink"><i class="fa fa-scissors"></i></a>
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" title="Insert picture (or just drag & drop)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></a>
                  <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
               </div>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="undo" title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default" data-edit="redo" title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
               </div>
               <input type="text" data-edit="inserttext" id="voiceBtn" x-webkit-speech="">
            </div>
            <div id="editor">
               Write email here&hellip;
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="emailComposeButtons">           
            <button class="btn btn-default">Discard Draft</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> Attach Files</button>
            <asp:LinkButton type="submit"  runat="server"   OnClick="Send_Click" ID="SendBtn"  CssClass="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Send</asp:LinkButton>
             <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" ID="sdzs">sfsfsfsf</asp:LinkButton>
             <asp:Button ID="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server"/>
             <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" onclick=" document.getElementById('btn').click();"></i>
         </div></div>
      </form>
   </body>

</html>
```

> c#

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BusinessLayer.EmailsController oEmailsController = new BusinessLayer.EmailsController();
    oEmailsController.Title = TextBoxTitle.Text;
    oEmailsController.PublishedDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxPublishDate.Text);
    oEmailsController.ExpiryDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxExpiryDate.Text);
    oEmailsController.FromGroupID = 1;
    string toIDs = TextBoxToIDs.Text;
    oEmailsController.FromID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('$')[2]);
    oEmailsController.SendStatus = (int)Enumeration.EmailSendStatus.send;
    oEmailsController.ToLevelGroupID = (int)Enumeration.EmailSendStatus.send;
    Response.Redirect("inbox.aspx", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing href="javascript:;" to href="javascript:void(0);" in your  tags